# "state.set is not a function" as part of my react-redux-immutable learning curve

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js, redux-thunk

The Action creator is getting called twice, it works just fine on the first case but not working as expected on the second call.
at first time.
This is happening consistently on the second call.

Writing the state to console before I am setting it, gets those interesting details, which isn't clear to me what I am doing wrong

this is the state as it seems for the first time, before setting it -
[image]

this is the state as it seems for the second call - 
[image]

```js
// The Action Creator
import config from "../../Config";
export const getLiveComments = () => {

    return (dispatch) => {
        fetchComments()
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok){
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }

                response.json().then(
                    comments => dispatch(gotComments(comments)))
            }
        ).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
        })
    };

};

function fetchComments(){
    return fetch(`${config.apiurl}/live-comments/get`, {
        method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
}

function gotComments(comments){
    return {
        type: 'GOT_COMMENTS',
        comments:comments
    }
}


//The Reducer
import Immutable from 'immutable';
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
    comments: []
});

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ("GOT_COMMENTS"):
            console.log('STATE (COMMENTS)', state)
            return state.set('comments', action.comments).toJS();
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

> reducer-live-comments.js:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: state.set is not a function
>       at ./src/common/ChatMessages/reducer-live-comments.js.**webpack_exports**.a (reducer-live-comments.js:10)
>       at combineReducers.js:39
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at combineReducers.js:36
>       at Map.withMutations (immutable.js:1353)
>       at combineReducers.js:35
>       at computeNextEntry (:2:27469)
>       at recomputeStates (:2:27769)
>       at :2:31382
>       at Object.dispatch (createStore.js:165)
>       at dispatch (:2:31875)
>       at index.js:14
>       at index.js:21
>       at dispatch (applyMiddleware.js:35)
>       at get-live-comments.js:22
>       at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your reducer.

`return state.set('comments', action.comments).toJS();`

Remove `.toJS()`

e.g: `const newState = state.setIn(['comments'], fromJS(action.comments))`

More info [here](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html)

Comment: Thanks. it works! will it work also for adding to a list, or should i use something else?

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `.toJS()` which is no longer an immutable object.

```
return state.set('comments', action.comments).toJS();
```

The next time your reducer runs, state will be a vanilla Object.

Remove `.toJS()`